# How to send unauthorized response status in json format in nodejs while using passport-jwt strategy in passport js?

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-jwt

I am using nodejs and passport js for authorization using passport-jwt strategy. Here is my code. It works with JWT token. But when token is not provided, it gives response in text format as "Unauthorized". I Want to customize it and make it in json format.

How to return customized json response when request is not authenticated.

```
 router.get('/users',passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), UserController.get);
```

Here is strategy definition.

```
var opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = CONFIG.jwt_encryption;

    passport.use(new Strategy(opts, async function(jwt_payload, done){
        let err, user;
        [err, user] = await to(User.findById(jwt_payload.user_id));

        if(err) return done(err, false);
        if(user) {
            return done(null, user);
        }else{
            return done(null, false);
        }
    }));
```